# print NaN value

Tags: c++, windows, printf, nan

How I make the following code work? I want to print "non defined" instead of -1.#IND00

```
int myprint(const char* format, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start (args, format);
    int ret;
    if(_isnan(static_cast<float>(*args)))
        ret = printf ("non defined");
    else
        ret = vprintf (format, args);
    fflush(stdout);
    va_end (args); 
    return ret; 
}

int main()
{
    myprint("%f", sqrt(-1.0));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Added C++ tag due to `static_cast`. Either change it to a C-style cast or stop reverting the tag change!

Comment: You'd have to write your own version of printf().  That's too painful, write a double-to-string conversion function instead so you can use %s in the printf format.

Comment: @Hans Passant - could you bring a code example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `args` like that, you have to use `va_arg` to get an actual argument.

```
if(_isnan(va_arg(args,double)))
```

would do the trick, but that won't help you much. You can't infer the type from the arguments. The type you indicate to `va_arg` must be the actual type of the object passed in.

And with that, your `vprintf` call won't work either, you need to "re-start" the va_list since `va_arg` has "consumed" one argument already.

Comment: how do I "re-start" the va_list?could you write a code for correct myprint implementation?

Comment: No, I can't write a correct version of your code. You'd need a complete re-implementation of `printf` - there are lots of open-source implementations out there. To restart the argument processing, you could simply `va_end(args); va_start(args, format);`.

Comment: Because `sqrt` is declared as `double sqrt(double x);`. The type you pass to `va_arg` **must match** the type you passed in to your function. Use `sqrtf` if your implementation has it, or convert to float at the call site if you want a float.